# Generator not catching error from API call

Tags: jestjs, generator

I'm working with an API that doesn't return anything "error-like" for an incorrect login (just a normal object with a code -- `incorrect_password` or `invalid_username` -- an HTML message), so in my API calling function I'm turning the code into an error:

```js
export async function loginWithApi(creds) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(ApiUrls.login, { params: creds });
    if (res.data.data) {
      return res.data;
    } else if (res.data.code) {
      throw Error(res.data.code.titleize());
    } // else, it should be an actual error
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}
```

This works correctly, throws correctly, returns an Error when it should.

However, when testing my saga generator action that calls this function, the error isn't being caught, it's going unabated through the `try` block:

#### function

```js
export function* loginSaga({ username, password }) {
  const creds = { username, password };
  try {
    const res = yield call(loginWithApi, creds);
    console.log(res);
    yield put({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: res.data });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", error });
  }
}
```

#### tests

```js
 describe("login action", () => {
    let gen;
    afterEach(() => {
      expect(gen.next().done).toBe(true);
    });

    it("should return a user object on a successful login", () => {
      gen = loginSaga(success.creds);
      gen.next(); // call api
      expect(gen.next(mockResponse.success).value).toEqual(
        put({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", user: mockResponse.success.data })
      );
    });

    it("should return an error when passed an invalid username", () => {
      gen = loginSaga(badUser.creds);
      gen.next(); // call api
      // mockReponse.usernameError: Error("Invalid Username")
      expect(gen.next(mockResponse.usernameError).value).toEqual(
        put({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", error: "Invalid Username" })
      );
    });

    it("should return an error when passed an invalid password", () => {
      gen = loginSaga(badPw.creds);
      gen.next(); // call api
      // mockResponse.passwordError: Error("Incorrect Password"),
      expect(gen.next(mockResponse.passwordError).value).toEqual(
        put({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", error: "Incorrect Password" })
      );
    });
  });
```

#### test output (excerpts)

```js
  ● Saga Actions › login action › should return an error when passed an invalid username

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "@@redux-saga/IO": true,
        "combinator": false,
        "payload": Object {
          "action": Object {
    -       "error": "Invalid Username",
    -       "type": "LOGIN_FAILURE",
    +       "type": "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    +       "user": undefined,
          },
          "channel": undefined,
        },
        "type": "PUT",

● Saga Actions › login action › should return an error when passed an invalid password

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
        "@@redux-saga/IO": true,
        "combinator": false,
        "payload": Object {
          "action": Object {
    -       "error": "Incorrect Password",
    -       "type": "LOGIN_FAILURE",
    +       "type": "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    +       "user": undefined,
          },
          "channel": undefined,
        },
        "type": "PUT",
      }
```

Logging confirms that the `loginSaga` function *is* receiving an `Error` in the second two tests. I can't quite determine why that error isn't being caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.

So you need make generator think that Exception happened for one of its `yield`. To make that we have [`generator.prototype.throw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw).

So next code should work as expected:

```
it("should return an error when passed an invalid username", () => {
  gen = loginSaga(badUser.creds);
  gen.next(); // call api
  // mockReponse.usernameError: Error("Invalid Username")
  expect(gen.throw(mockResponse.usernameError).value).toEqual(
    put({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", error: "Invalid Username" })
  );
});
```